# "for almost all" symbol

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

Is there a standard symbol for “for all but finitely many”? I had a professor who used to make an inverted capital lambda crossed by a little concave arc. And I found it in *Super-recursive algorithms* by Mark Burgin denoted by $\forall\forall$.

Comment: $\approx \forall$      ;) 

I have never seen any notation, but $\forall \forall$ is what I would probably default to of the two you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use (and I often see in others' writing) $\forall^\infty$ meaning "for all but finitely many" and $\exists^\infty$ for the dual quantifier, "for infinitely many".

Answer (score 1):

I've sometimes come across, $\;\forall\forall\;$ to mean "almost all".

I've mostly encountered $\;\forall^\infty\;$ used to represent: "assymptopically almost surely", "all bar finitely many", or "almost all".